# Can I use mac dump_syms for iOS application?

Tags: ios, google-breakpad

I want to generate symbols for an iOS application, but Google break-pad has only mac `dump_syms`, I didn't find it for iOS. Can I use it for iOS? When I try, I get this error:

```
/Users/user/google-breakpad-read-only/src/tools/mac/dump_syms/build/Debug/dump_syms 
-g /Users/user/TestBreakpad/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestBreakpad.app.dSYM 
/Users/user/TestBreakpad/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestBreakpad.app 
Unable to find DWARF-bearing file in bundle: /Users/user/TestBreakpad/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestBreakpad.app
```

I tried to build this using iOS SDK but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It needs full path to your binary, not just the bundle:

```
  /Users/user/TestBreakpad/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestBreakpad.app/Contents/bla/TestBreakpad
```